# create table rows of 4 in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have these checkboxes, I'm trying to create rows of 4 checkboxes. At the moment it creates one row.

```
<table>
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes :expertise_ids, Expertise.all, :id, :name do |b| %>
      <td>
        <label style="margin-left:5px; margin-right:15px;" class="checkbox-inline">
         <%= b.check_box %>
         <%= b.label %>
        </label>
      </td>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Iv have tried something like this:

```
<table>
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes :expertise_ids, Expertise.all, :id, :name do |b| %>
    <% tablerows = 0 %>
      <td>
        <label style="margin-left:5px; margin-right:15px;" class="checkbox-inline">
         <%= b.check_box %>
         <%= b.label %>
         <% tablerows += 1 %>
         <% break if tablerows == 3 %>
        </label>
      </td>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Im trying something like this to iterate over and every time is counts to 4 in trying to generate a new row, but I'm not sure how to complete this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`in_groups_of`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/Array.html#method-i-in_groups_of):

```
<table>
  <% Expertise.all.in_groups_of(4, false) do |expertise_group| %>
    <tr><!-- a new row for each group of four -->
      <%= f.collection_check_boxes :expertise_ids, expertise_group, :id, :name do |b| %>
         <td><!-- each checkbox get a column on its own -->
           <label style="margin-left:5px; margin-right:15px;" class="checkbox-inline">
             <%= b.check_box %>
             <%= b.label %>
           </label>
        </td>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap them inside a `tr` tag. Plus you set your counter like this.

```
<table>
  <% tablerow = 0 %>
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes :expertise_ids, Expertise.all, :id, :name do |b| %>
    <% break if tablerow == 4; tablerow += 1; %>
    <tr>
      <td>
         <label style="margin-left:5px; margin-right:15px;" class="checkbox-inline">
           <%= b.check_box %>
           <%= b.label %>
         </label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider a flexbox? The wrapping logic would take care of itself.

https://jsfiddle.net/c41pL74r/2/

Just make sure any margin/padding is added on the elements within the `div`s and not directly on them, otherwise you'll need to deliberately account for the width with `calc()`.